# comparing arrays in PHP - interesting behaviour

Tags: php, arrays, compare

The first example:

```
$x = array("a" => 1, "b" => 2); 
$y = array("b" => 1, "a" => 2);
$xLessY = ($x < $y);
$xGreaterY = ($x > $y);
var_dump($xLessY, $xGreaterY);
```

**Result**: $xLessY = *true*, $xGreaterY = *true*

The second example:

```
$x = array("a" => 2, "b" => 1); 
$y = array("b" => 2, "a" => 1);
$xLessY = ($x < $y);
$xGreaterY = ($x > $y);
var_dump($xLessY, $xGreaterY);
```

**Result**: $xLessY = *false*, $xGreaterY = *false*

According to documentation on http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php:

> if key from operand 1 is not found in
>   operand 2 then arrays are
>   uncomparable, otherwise - compare
>   value by value

In our case each key from array $x is present in array $y, so $x and $y are comparable.
See also the example from documentation:

```
// Arrays are compared like this with standard comparison operators
function standard_array_compare($op1, $op2)
{
    if (count($op1) < count($op2)) {
        return -1; // $op1 < $op2
    } elseif (count($op1) > count($op2)) {
        return 1; // $op1 > $op2
    }
    foreach ($op1 as $key => $val) {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $op2)) {
            return null; // uncomparable
        } elseif ($val < $op2[$key]) {
            return -1;
        } elseif ($val > $op2[$key]) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0; // $op1 == $op2
}
```

This behaviour is really strange: $x is less than $y and at the same time $x is greater than $y (the first example) and two arrays are comparable.

I think this is because php always compares starting from the one definite side of sign '<'. I mean: for ($x < $y) php takes $x as operand 1, for ($x > $y) it takes $y as operand 1. Although I didn't find anything about this behaviour in documentation.
What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: I suspect that you might be right about how whichever value is on the pointy end of `<` gets used as the 1st operand.  Of course, you can find the answer for sure if you look at the PHP source code...

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is correct. The `>` operator is parsed as

```
|   expr '>' expr { zend_do_binary_op(ZEND_IS_SMALLER, &$$, &$3, &$1 TSRMLS_CC); }
```

This basically says, `X > Y` is equivalent to `not X < Y`, which is of course wrong when the comparison is not commutative. Consider reporting this on bugs.php.net.

Comment: Commutative? `X > Y` being commutative means that `X > Y` is equivalent `Y > X`. Plus, you say "the comparison (which comparison btw) not being commutative" implies `X > Y` not being equivalent to `not X < Y`. Follows from contraposition that `X > Y` being equivalent to `not X < Y` implies the comparison being commutative, which is obviously a nonsensical statement. Plus, the bug is not there, because the manual states that the two operand are indeed comparable, so one would expect antisymmetry, which is not verified because `$x > $y` and `$y > $x` is true with `$x != $y`.

Comment: I agree there's no sensible way to order associative arrays, but this doesn't mean having some arbitrary order set up is not useful -- for instance, many algorithms depend on the data being ordered. However, the current state of affairs is that not only there isn't a total order in the universe of arrays, but also the arrays for which the manual states there's a well-defined order don't actually have consistency between `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say the bug is in `$x > $y` being substituted for `$y < $x`.

Sure, if you implemented `$x > $y` in a way that the arguments did not exchange positions when passed to the comparison function, you would solve this particular problem. But you get another in return.

Right now you have:

```
$x < $y <=> cmp($x, $y) == -1
$x > $y <=> cmp($y, $x) == -1
```

Because the first key of the first argument is always compared first, both conditions are true if `reset($x) < $y[key($x)]` and `reset($y) < $x[key($y)]`.

But consider another implementation, which would solve this problem:

```
$x < $y <=> cmp($x, $y) == -1
$x > $y <=> cmp($x, $y) == +1
```

Now `<` and `>` are consistent when the order of the operands is fixed, but we now get weird behavior when we swap the operands because we could still have `cmp($x, $y) == -1` and `cmp($y, $x) == -1`, which would mean `$x < $y` and `$y < $x` would both be true.

In sum, the only solution would be to fix the comparison function so that its behavior was antisymmetric, i.e. so that `cmp($x, $y) == - cmp($y, $x)`, at least within a set of elements that are claimed to be comparable.

Comment: I think this behaviour `$x < $y == -1` and `$y < $x == -1` is more understandable in case unordered arrays. And this is more consistent with the documentation.

Comment: Maybe this is not a bug, but they should document that

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but I don't think you can compare arrays that way. I always assumed one can check for equality or inequality, but not compare quantities with < and >.

The [man page on array operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) seems to confirm this.

Comment: There is [another man page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). See the table "Comparison with Various Types" and the text below: "Array with fewer members is smaller, if key from operand 1 is not found in operand 2 then arrays are uncomparable, otherwise - compare value by value (see following example)". And there is also the example (standard_array_compare function) that I wrote